# 'React' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following [the official reactjs](http://reactjs.org/) instructions to create a sample app. My node version is 6.9.0.

I created sample react app which is supposed to display a empty tic tac toe table according to the official website using following instructions:

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app my-app`

`cd my-app`

changed to **my-app** directory

removed the default files inside the source directory as directed. Now
my **index.js** looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
```

Then I ran `yarn start`

But all I see is blank screen no tic tac toe table. And couple warnings in the console saying

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/index.js
  Line 1:  'React' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
  Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Comment: Well if that is all that is in your index.js then the errors are self explanatory, you never use either of those variables. Also your page won't show up in the console / command window that is to just start the server. To view your page you point your browser to your local servers url

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay I understand that I am new to reactjs. But then why does the documentation say `Now if you run npm start in the project folder and open http://localhost:3000 in the browser, you should see an empty tic-tac-toe field.`. I just did whatever it says.

Answer (score 4):

You missed last parts in steps 4 & 5:

> 4. Add a file named index.css in the src/ folder with [this CSS code](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/oWWQNa?editors=0100).
> 5. Add a file named index.js in the src/ folder with [this JS code](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/oWWQNa?editors=0010).

index.css

```
body {
  font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

ol, ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.kbd-navigation .square:focus {
  background: #ddd;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

index.js

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {/* TODO */}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create some component/element/, maybe style it, then call `ReactDOM` to render your component to the underlying html and then you will have it.

- `React` is used to handle JSX and creation of React component
- `ReactDOM` in your simple case will be used to render created element to dom.

See here : https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html

So ading something like

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

to your code, you will get something if in your `index.html` there is element with `id="root"` inside `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

ESlint needs to be configured to work with React JSX. This excellent [article](https://medium.com/@RossWhitehouse/setting-up-eslint-in-react-c20015ef35f7) has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means your project has eslint configured to catch unused variables.

If you use JSX or anything React within that file the warning will go away just like suggested by zmii in his answer.

But i am writing this answer because someone showed me their code and they were facing the same problem.

Their code :

```
import React from 'react';

const person = () => {
    return "<h2>I am a person!</h2>"
};

export default person;
```

The problem in the above code was that while returning, he used double quotes. So instead of JSX, it was returning string and therefore they were getting error that React was never not used.

Conclusion: Syntax are important so keep in mind, specially if you are starting out.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am using react 18+. Along with double quotes if we need to have the first letter of person as upper case then only React DOM is rendering the component, Person.